# Error when connecting button in Swift Custom Keyboard

Tags: swift, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm creating a custom keyboard extension written in Swift. I'm trying to design the keyboard visually using a Nib (.xib) file. I'm getting an error when trying to connect a button.

I found that my Nib (KeyboardView) wouldn't show up unless I explicitly added it in my KeyboardViewController's viewDidLoad() method:

```
self.view.addSubview(UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView)
```

I then connected a button from my Nib which generated this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
```

When I test my keyboard I get the following error: 'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextKeyboardButton.'

If I remove the connection, the error disappears and the keyboard shows up correctly. I'm using the built-in Custom Keyboard template and haven't added any code besides adding the subview above and a single button in the Nib.

Answer (score 2):

Found my problem, had to specify the owner (self) when loading my nib:

```
self.view.addSubview(UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView)
```